# How to give property a Value from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 classes: `FrmMenu` and `FrmProperty`. In `FrmProperty` I created a property like this:

```
public string ApplicationString { get; set; }

form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ApplicationString);
}
```

Then, I instantiate that class in `FrmMenu`, like this:

```
FrmProperty frmp = new FrmProperty();
//Give value
frmp.ApplicationString = "1";
frmp.ShowDialog();
```

This code should transfer a value from `FrmMenu` to `FrmProperty`. Why doesn't this work? The MessageBox is blank.

Comment: try messagebox.show(frmp.ApplicationString); on the onload of fmMenu

Comment: Has your Form-load-event really a blabla-Parameterlist? However, when you instatntiate your Property-form within the first one, the ApplicationString should be "1". What sais your Debugger what it is else? Btw.: how did you declare messagebox?

Comment: @Izikon : it show the value i asign for, it's "1"

Comment: @HimBromBeere : yea it should be 1. How to use a debugger? i fixed my declare messagebox in my first post, u can check it, i just type it manually here before

Comment: There's something else going on here.  I put together a very simply app with 2 forms.  The first had a button on it with your code for instantiating FrmProperty.  FrmProperty was defined almost exactly as you have it.  The only difference was my load method was `private void FrmProperty_Load( ...`  When I clicked the button, the message box dialog showed the `"1"` value

Comment: I checked the code working fine for me without any problems

Comment: hmm... any suggestion how can i track, why mine is not working? :(

Answer (score 0):

So, I've tried this out myself and the first thing to note is that the code you supply does not compile. Your example has:

```
form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ApplicationString);
}
```

but this would be better writen as:

```
private void FrmProperty_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ApplicationString);
}
```

Perhaps that is self explanatory but I find it always helps to make sure everything is as clear as possible.

In terms of your problem, the only thing I can possibly think of that would make your code fail to work using the above is if you had not wired up the `FrmProperty_Load` method to the Load event of `FrmProperty`.

The `FrmProperty_Load` method won't run unless something asks it to, so in the constructor for `FrmProperty` add the following:

```
this.Load += FrmProperty_Load;
```

Your `FrmMenu` class should remain unchanged and your `FrmProperty` class should look roughly like the following:

```
public partial class FrmProperty : Form
{
    public string ApplicationString { get; set; }

    public FrmProperty()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += FrmProperty_Load;
    }

    private void FrmProperty_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ApplicationString);
    }

}
```

Comment: @KeVin Did you add the `this.Load += FrmProperty_Load;` in the constructor? Can you post more of your code?